# Ansible: setup a cron job on one host

Tags: cron, ansible

I'm deploying a 2-hosts service that also needs to setup a cron job. This job should only be run on one of the two machines (I dont care which). what's the easiest way to do so?

- I know that the shell module in Ansible supports "run_once", but the cron module does not.
- I could setup the cron job on both machines and then use the command "crontab -r" to remove all the jobs (provided no other jobs are needed there) on one machine. this is dirty, but very easy.

any better ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that the shell module in Ansible supports "run_once", but the cron module does not.

Wrong. `run_once` is a property of a task, not of action modules.

Use `cron` module and set `run_once` for the task (mind the indentation level), for example:

```
- cron:
    name: "check dirs"
    minute: "0"
    hour: "5,2"
    job: "ls -alh > /dev/null"
  run_once: true
```